# Python float type causing invalid result?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Imagine you have the following df:

```
dffinal =  {'BTW': '2.81', 'ExclBTW': '31.17', Totaal: '33.98'}

    BTW     ExclBTW Totaal  
0   2.81    31.17   33.98
```

dtype:

I want to do a reconciliation check on these numbers, such that Totaal equals ExclBTW + BTW:

```
dffinal['VATcheck'] = np.where(dffinal['Totaal'].astype('float') == (dffinal['ExclBTW'].astype(float) + dffinal['BTW'].astype(float)), True, False)
```

However, the VATcheck returns False, while 2.81 + 31.17 = 33.98:

```
     BTW    ExclBTW Totaal  VATcheck
0   2.81    31.17   33.98   False
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Please help!

Comment: floating point precision. Use `np.isclose` instead of `==` comparison.

Comment: Why are you calling `round()` on one side of the equation but not the other?

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry that was an error

Comment: @QuangHoang how would you implement this?

Comment: `dffinal['VATcheck'] = np.isclose(dffinal['Totaal'], dffinal['ExclBTW'] + dffinal['BTW'])` given they are all floats.